# JavaFX - Generics MVVM bad type

Tags: java, generics, mvvm, javafx-8

I have a generic `ItemsView`, which takes a `ItemsViewModel` and everything is injected using Guice.

```
public abstract class ItemsView<T extends ItemsViewModel> {
    private T viewModel;
}

public class ModelItemsView<T extends ModelViewModel> extends ItemsView<T>{}
```

And the ViewModels:

```
public abstract ItemsViewModel{
    protected abstract void load();
}


public ModelItemsViewModel extends ItemsViewModel{
    @Override
    protected void load(){
        loader.loadAll();
    }

public ModelByFilterItemsViewModel extends ModelItemsViewModel{
    @Override
    protected void load(){
        loader.loadByFilter();
    }
}
```

And the `ModelItemsView` is nested inside another view, so when I call

```
@FXML
public ModelItemsView<ModelByFilterItemsViewModel> itemsController;
```

It takes the configuration of the `ModelItemsViewModel` not the filtered one, because somehow the `viewModel` property is of type `ModelItemsViewModel` not `ModelByFilterItemsViewModel` as it should be.

Comment: Are you sure it's right code? Your `ModelItemsViewModel` and `ModelByFilterItemsViewModel` don't extend `ItemsViewModel`. And itemsController has two models in it's type `ModelItemsViewModel<ModelByFilterItemsViewModel>` not something like `ItemsView<ModelByFilterItemsViewModel>` like first class in your example... What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev Sorry, thanks for noticing, updated

Comment: still, is line `public ModelItemsViewModel<ModelByFilterItemsViewModel> itemsController;` correct? How both ViewModle classes are connected with `ItemsView`? (sorry, but your class naming is really confusing)

Comment: @SergeyGrinev Ohhh I didn't notice that, must have been distracted. all the dependencies, including the ViewModels are injected with guice.

Comment: Sorry, can't find any problems in current code, so I guess there may be something wrong with your injection code.

Comment: @SergeyGrine Me neither, it seems that Fxml loading doesn't support this kind of thing.